# 'more than 200 times that of ...' vs. 'more than 200 times than that of ...'

Tags: grammar, phrases

While I was studying a textbook, I came across a sentence like this: ''The affinity of carbon monoxide for haemoglobin is more than 200 times that of oxygen.''

Am I correct in assuming that there should be another ''than'' in the sentence and the whole sentence should be like: ''The affinity of carbon monoxide for haemoglobin is more than 200 times **than** that of oxygen.'' ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correct; we do not use 'than' when using only 'times' to express a ratio, in your case 200 to one. If you used an adjective of comparison, e.g. more, bigger, larger, etc, you would write 'than'.

The price of gold per kilogramme is $60,000. The price of lead per kilogramme is $2.

> The price of gold per kilogramme is 30,000 **times** that of lead.
>
> The price of gold per kilogramme is 30,000 **times bigger than** that
> of lead.